# How can I release two apks in android studio under a same package?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a shopping app, where there exists seller side and customer side. So I need to deploy a individual app for seller and for customers. My question is how can I create those under a single package?

Since because my app needs to communicate to firebase real-time database. Under firebase real-time free plan, only one app allowed for one database, maximum number of database can be created under free plan is 1. It recognizing the app on the basis of the package. That's why I need how to create two apk under one package in android studio. Please help me out.

Currently using Android studio v3.3.

Comment: Merge those two databases into _one_ firebase realtime database.

Comment: If by "package" you mean "application ID"... it is not possible for two different apps to be installed at the same time, or distributed on the Play Store at the same time, with the same application ID.

Comment: use Build Flavor & varients  for that
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Comment: One project, multiple variants will let you use the free plan and restrict yourself to single database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sub packages for example

```
com.my.shop  //the package
com.my.shop.clients  //1st sub-package
com.my.shop.sellers  //2nd sub-package
```

Then write different screens for the subpackages like the first activity can allow users to choose if they are Client or Seller.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

package id (app id) is needs to be unique. you can't publish on google play.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution, make your first screen for shopping app customer side with a hide (at the button of screen or something like this) button for seller and when they click on it, redirect them to another screen for "second" apks.

Answer (score 0):

Write **one app**, create **two sub-package** inside it. For instance:

```
**com.mybrand** // Main package, general-shared codes and screens. This will be your package name and used by Google Play, Firebase etc.

*com.mybrand.customer* // Customer specific screen and codes

*com.mybrand.seller* // Seller specific screen and codes
```

In this way, codes and screens will be seperated in the same app. If you will decide seperate them in future, you can easily seperate and publish them without any name or package name confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, **package must be unique**. You can create packages with flavors in gradle:

```
android {
...

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    versionCode 10
     ...
}

flavorDimensions "flavor"

productFlavors {
    customer {
        flavorDimension "flavor"
        applicationId "com.example.customer"
    }

    seller {
        flavorDimension "flavor"
        applicationId "com.example.seller"
    }
  }

 ... 
}
```

or

```
android {
...

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    versionCode 10
    applicationId "com.example"
}

flavorDimensions "flavor"

productFlavors {
    customer {
        flavorDimension "flavor"
        applicationIdSuffix '.customer'
    }

    seller {
        flavorDimension "flavor"
        applicationIdSuffix '.seller'
    }
  }

 ... 
}
```